# Maven2 WTP version for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, maven-2, jakarta-ee

I want to use Maven 2 for buliding Web App using Spring 3.05 and Hibernate 3.6 on Tomcat 6 and JDK 1.6.20

In order to convert Maven WEb Project to Eclipse Web Project I need to use the following command:

```
mvn -Dwtpversion=[something] eclipse:eclipse
```

In Maven+ Eclipse documentation I can see that The plugin actually can create WTP R7, 1.0, 1.5 and 2.0 configuration files.

Which version should I use in my case? 
What are the other versions need for?
If I check in Eclipse it seems like I have WTP 3.1.1 installed.

Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.codehaus.org) - *eclipse plugin for maven* support, you can import the maven project to eclipse without needing to run *maven eclipse plugin*.  This will save you the trouble of having to specify version.